# How to make RSpec recognize slim templates?

Tags: rspec, rubygems

I have a trivialized controller action in a module

```
module MyEngine
  module UsersControllerExt
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def index
      @users = User.relevant
      render template: "users/index"
    end

  end
end
```

And an RSpec controller concern spec using anonymous controller

```
RSpec.describe MyEngine::UsersControllerExt, type: :controller do
  controller(ApplicationController) do
    include MyEngine::UsersControllerExt
  end

  describe "GET :show" do
    it "should set @users instance variable" do
      get :index

      expect(assigns(:users)).to be_present      
    end
  end

end
```

This spec fails with

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template users/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]}. Searched in:
     * "~/Documents/my_engine/spec/dummy/app/views"
     * "~/Documents/my_engine/app/views"
```

If I change the template file `index.slim` to `index.erb`, the spec passes.
How do I make RSpec accept slim templates?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have `s.add_development_dependency "slim"` in gemspec
2. Make sure your test environment loads the gem with `require 'slim'` in `rails_helper.rb` for example